# How to Check for unsaved changes when switching nested views in a same Page?

Tags: angularjs

When we are switch between one state to another state here i am able to check `unsaved changes` and i can ask user for conformation before moving one page to another but in a same view i have multiple forms in that if am switch between one form to another form first **i have to to give message to the user are you sure u want leave page without saving the data**  then only i can move to another form How can i do this.

example of multiple forms in same view below i have metioned

```
<div ng-switch-when="formTab">
  <div ng-include="'/views/tmpl/workForm.html'"></div>
</div>
<div ng-switch-when="effortTab">
   <div ng-include="'/views/tmpl/workEffort.html'"></div>
</div>
```

In the above example while moving from **formTab** to **effortTab** i need to show that **unsaved changes** message

Comment: Can you create fiddle?
Solution should be something like use $dirty to check form status.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$dirty` property of the [form](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController):

```
console.log(myForm.$dirty);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zlCsVWVJ5Y1nO5830CFN?p=preview)

Comment: i will be storing the form name in `$scope.FormNm` because while switch between forms i have to check validation based on form name, so how i can do validation for scope variable  like `$scope.FormNm.$valid` .

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this Instead of using ng-switch we can use nested states with the parent state.

using `unsavedChanges directive` we can check automatically whether any unsaved data is there in the current form. if condition matches this directive will warn the user this will work based on `ui-state` so it will check automatically when we are injected directive no need to do manually..

Below example

```
$stateProvider.state('edit', {
abstract: true,
url: '/edit',
templateUrl: 'edit.html',
controller: function($scope) {
  $scope.model = {};
  $scope.validator = {
    basic: null,
    extended: null,
    isValid: function() {
      return this.basic && this.extended;
    } 
  };
 }}).
   state('edit.formTab', {
   url: '/formTab',
   templateUrl: 'formTab.html',
   controller: function($scope) {
   $scope.$watch('formTab.$valid', function(value) {
       $scope.validator.formTab= value;
    });
  }}).
   state('edit.effortTab', {
   url: '/effortTab',
   templateUrl: 'effortTab.html',
   controller: function($scope) {
   $scope.$watch('effortTab.$valid', function(value) {
      $scope.validator.effortTab= value;
   });
 }});
```

we can use below link :
http://plnkr.co/edit/OyVBpp?p=preview